# Git cannot handle LOG internally

Tags: git

I accidentally typed a Git command in uppercase and got this error:

```
❯ git LOG
fatal: cannot handle LOG internally
```

It happens for other otherwise-valid commands:

```
fatal: cannot handle COMMIT internally
fatal: cannot handle ADD internally
```

And so on.

However, completely invalid commands produce a more familiar error message:

```
❯ git nonsense
git: 'nonsense' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

❯ git NONSENSE
git: 'NONSENSE' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

What is the difference between these cases, and is there any significance to the first error?

I am using Git 1.8 on OSX Mavericks:

```
❯ git --version
git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)
```

Comment: for `git version 2.0.1` `git LOG`shows `git: 'LOG' is not a git command. See 'git --help'`.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Weird. I'm using Git 2.0.1 and `git LOG` outputs `fatal: cannot handle LOG as a builtin`.

Comment: Maybe it is environment sensitive. I'm using OSX Mavericks.

Comment: I'm using Debian Jessie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason can be found in git source code tagged with v1.8.5.2 (the version you have) [in file git.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v1.8.5.2/git.c#L572)

It recognises `LOG` as internal command name, but then fails to handle it, because there is only lowercase `log` in the command lookup table.

In short - the different messages are caused by different code paths and it is simply a bug - there is no significant significance.

This has also been rewritten in later versions - [compare it to current version in master branch here.](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git.c)

Answer (score 1):

In older versions the output used to be `git: 'LOG' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

```
git version 1.7.9.5
```

Comment: Looks like a regression to me.